# Web browser history question

Tags: multithreading, browser, browser-history

Were publicly available web browsers ever single-threaded? If so, when did multithreaded browsers become mainstream?

Comment: Google Chrome was the first multi-thread browsers that uses seperate process with it's own memory for each tab.. So I'd say since about 2008.

Comment: @rsplak Would Firefox's separated process for plugins count?

Comment: @Shaz, good one, depends on what user428621 means by his question! Haven't thought of the plugins, +1

Comment: @rsplak, that's not multi-threaded, that's multi-process.  And IE8 beat Chrome to that by a few months.

Comment: I mean within the browser; for something like processing a request, loading images, etc, where if it were a single thread you could have a backlog. Did we always have multitreaded browsing?

Answer (score 0):

[Mosaic-ck](http://www.floodgap.com/retrotech/machten/mosaic/) doesn't appear to use threads, except for the MacOS launcher, which suggests that the original Mosaic didn't use threads.

It might use some other parallel operation like select(), I haven't checked in detail.